# ng-options track by issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a select dropdown

```
 <select ng-model="filter_cli" ng-options=" gc.id as gc.name for gc in
 businesses | filter :{type : 'CLIENT'} track by gc.id">
```

When Selecting in the app, the selected value is not being displayed but is being assigned. Removing "track by" solves the issue but then the value of the options needs to be the id of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to move your `track by` to before your filter:

```
<select ng-model="filter_cli" ng-options=" gc.id as gc.name for gc in
businesses track by gc.id | filter :{type : 'CLIENT'}">
```

Comment: had already tried that. In this case the filtering doesn't work.